# Filter cells that contain “TUN”

Tags: vba, excel

Why won’t the VBA below take out cells that contain “TUN” in Column U in a dataset that ranges from 30-40k. It only takes out some but not all.
———

```
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$21322").AutoFilter Field:=21,        Criteria1:=Array( _
        "TUN"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("A2:Z2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("A3:AB30000").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A2:Z2").Select
    ChDir "C:\Users\soulagep\Documents\Custom Office Templates"
End Sub
```

——-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "*" wildcard to filter anything that contains the group of characters "TUN" ignoring capitals

```
Sub test()

Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$21322").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=**TUN**", Operator:=xlAnd
Range("A2:Z2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range("A3:AB30000").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A2:Z2").Select
ChDir "C:\Users\soulagep\Documents\Custom Office Templates"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @pnuts, I agree with you avoiding `select` in this case I just provided the solution for filtering the range containing "TUN"

Comment: Thanks y'all! This worked great. Any advice on adding multiple criterial. as in if the cell contains "TUN" or "SAP".

Answer (score 1):

I would completely avoid using `.Select`. This causes unnecessary processing time and is very inefficient, especially in your case with you being in the tens of thousands of rows. Not to mention, in some cases it can be unreliable.

Instead, load your data to an array, and if the array data equals "TUN", add it to a special range. Once you process the entire data, delete the special range (in this case, `delRng`).

```
Sub TEST()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, filterArr() As Variant
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    filterArr = ws.Range("U:U").Value

    Dim delRng As Range, i As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(filterArr)
        If filterArr(i, 1) Like "*TUN*" Then
            If delRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRng = ws.Rows(i)
            Else
                Set delRng = Union(ws.Rows(i), delRng)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice code @K.Davis, why not use the `AutoFilter` method?, loading the data to an Array is faster?